# is a certain report available?

Tags: reports

I am the Treasurer of small not-for-profit organization and we use CIVI for our donations database.  I see that CIVI has a "Repeat Contributions" report that can show a comparison of total $$ donated amount by person for two consecutive years.  This is good; however, I would like to see ONE report that lists the total donations for each person for our 5 years; that is, think ....column A has the name, and Columns B,C,D,E,F shows the annual contribution amount for that year.  Can this be done?  and if so, how?
Thank you - Mary - (Treasurer)

Comment: Mary - if you don't get a good answer for doing this via civi reports, then if you are using Drupal there could be a Views alternative solution.

Comment: Let me know if you are on drupal and i can provide more guidance as i expect it may require views_field_view module to pull year specific data in to each column

Answer (score 3):

The Aggregated Household Contributions extension by Allen Shaw at Emphanos will get you close. It creates a report template for the Contribution Aggregate by Relationship report. The report will show up to 5 years of history by year (you can choose to show less) and a total if you want it. However by default it groups contacts into households, shows the contributions for the individuals in the household, and then shows the total for the household by each year (which is actually a really nice thing to have). If someone is not in a household, it will just show the individual giving history. If you don't know how to load extensions, you can reach out to your sys admin or post another question.

Comment: https://civicrm.org/extensions/aggregate-household-contributions-report

Answer (score 2):

Mary, I do not think there is a standard report that does that. You could create a customized report (or ask a CiviCRM partner to do it for you) that shows the data like you explain. 
And I agree with the suggestion that petednz made about Drupal Views.